# Get Facebook Page Feed and their likes/comments without any permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am trying to get the user ids of all the users who have liked or commented on a status on a facebook page.
I tried using graph.facebook.com/page_id/posts?access_token=...
but it only gives me 2-4 user ids who have liked and their total count, similarly for comments. Is there any way to get all the ids?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation at all? doesn't accessing the post directly return more comments and likes?

Comment: On accessing the post directly gives you 4 users who have liked and 4 comments only.

Answer (score 0):

According to [The Documentation for the 'Post' object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)
 (and verified by me on my own page using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) tool), these work:

- `/POST_ID/comments` to fetch the comments
- `/POST_ID/likes`to fetch the Likes